# How to prevent a ReorderableListView overlays the AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

From the example code provided by the official docs, how can I prevent that a `ReorderableListView` overlays the `AppBar` and therefore also a `BottomNavigationBar` when dragging one of its tiles?

Maybe there is a way to constraint the draggable area of the underlying `OverlayEntry`.

```
void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: CustomList()));

class CustomList extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomList> createState() => _CustomListState();
}

class _CustomListState extends State<CustomList> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(5, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Custom List')),
      body: ReorderableListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
        children: <Widget>[
          for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index += 1)
            ListTile(
              key: Key('$index'),
              title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
            ),
        ],
        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
              newIndex -= 1;
            }
            final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
            _items.insert(newIndex, item);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try Using SafeArea() or Stack() Widget.